# What is the object scope and lifetime in the different ASP.NET MVC components?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scope, lifetime

The ASP.NET MVC has many components. Controllers, actions, static classes, ApiControllers, Filters, RouteTables, BundleTables, Factories, et cetera along with access modifiers to controller scope.

If we instantiate an object or access a static property within any of these, how do we determine the object's, class's, or member's scope and lifetime. Take this example for instance:

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static object MyProperty { get; set; }
    public static Func<object> MyPropertyFactory { get; set; }

    static MyHelper()
    {
        MyProperty = new object();
        MyPropertyFactory = () => new object();
    }
}
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public object MyAppProperty { get; set; }
    public object MyRequestProperty { get; set; }

    public MyController()
    {
        MyAppProperty = MyHelper.MyProperty;
        MyRequestProperty = MyHelper.MyPropertyFactory;
    }

    public object MyAction()
    {
        var MyActionObject = new object();
        return MyActionObject;
    }
}
```

I find the lifetime and scope of the different objects and static class properties difficult to parse. This gets my into threading and other problems.

Other than analysis and experience, is there a generally process for determining this? Another more answerable question is: "What is the lifetime and scope of each of the following and why?

- MyHelper
- MyHelper.MyProperty
- MyHelper.MyPropertyFactory
- MyController
- MyController.MyAppProperty
- MyController.MyRequestProperty
- MyController.MyAction.MyActionObject

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All static properties have AppDomain lifetime (from first usage to shutdown/restart).

Others (Controllers, models and views) - request lifetime (created during request, eligible for GC after end of that request).

Comment: This is the answer because it gives a pithy and clear answer. I was wondering, "What has AppDomain lifetime, what has request lifetime, and are there any other lifetime categories." From your answer, it seems that AppDomain and Request are the only two lifetime categories. Is that right?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin AppDomain and Request lifetime are two most interesting cases for ASP.Net application. Indeed you can get more detailed estimates (i.e. controller is gone before corresponding view is created), but for most practical purposes these two are enough (i.e. to know if something will survive to next request).

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest to use Dependency Injection container. Your problem with lifetime-scoping will go away, because the container will manage all of these for you.

Instead of static initiations and messing about with functions-factories you'll do:

```
private readonly IService service;
private readonly IOtherService otherService;

public MyController(IService service, IOtherService)
{
    this.service = service;
    this.otherService = otherService;
}
```

Comment: This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx) and the ASP.NET MVC Identity template code in VS 2013 are what spawned my question. I like and use dependency injection. In the Identity blog post, Microsoft uses and recommends the Factory Pattern, "This is a recommended way of getting an instance of UserManager per request for the application." It's of note that they say it is "a recommended was" not "the recommended way." Maybe Dependency Injection is a better model. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Many Microsoft examples ignore DI containers and just spawn new objects as they please. I'd take that recommendation with a pinch of salt. Also I'd study the source code of the factory and check if it is really controlling lifetime scope for created objects.

Comment: So just to be clear, these injected services live longer than 1 request?

Comment: @Lawyerson it depends how your DI is configured. Usually it is recommended to have a request to be the lifescope, i.e. objects are re-created on every request, but you can have other lifescopes like singleton.

Comment: Does the DI container create a new instance of the controller at each request?

Comment: @variable depends on hour DI is configured. But I'd imagine default stance would be to create new objects per every request, including controllers.